# aws ses with html template in node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using node with express framework. I need to implement aws ses mail. I have added following code snippets:

```
 var aws = require('aws-sdk');  // package used   

  // mailing part
  ses.sendEmail({
    Source: from,
    Destination: { ToAddresses: [to] },
    Message: {
        Subject: {
            Data: subject
        },
        Body: {
            Html: {
                Charset: 'UTF-8',
                Data: message,
            }
        }
    }
```

it works fine if message is a string with minimal html tags.
But i need to add a html page or i need to add a custom template. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

```
   ses.sendTemplatedEmail({
    Source: from,
    Destination: { ToAddresses: [to] },
    Template : "sample",
    TemplateData: "{ \"name\":\"Alejandro\", \"favoriteanimal\": \"alligator\" }"
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, true );
});
```

i have tried this one also. What i get is, 
**sendTemplatedEmail is not a function**

Comment: Since sending email templates is a new functionality in SES, you might need to update your `aws-sdk` package.

Comment: ok thanks.. i will update and check